# Create a group to disallow display breaks?

Tags: grouping, displaybreak

I have an `\allowdisplaybreaks` command in my document, but I want to create a section where there aren't any. Is any any command that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Section 3.9 of the [User’s Guide for the `amsmath` Package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf): “When display breaks are enabled with `\allowdisplaybreaks`, the `\\*` command can be used to prohibit a pagebreak after a given line, as usual.” Or, you can try issuing `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` after the section header to “allow page breaks, but avoid them as much as possible”.

The undocumented usage `\allowdisplaybreaks[0]` is supposed to disallow pagebreaks altogether. By default, `\allowdisplaybreaks` is the same as `\allowdisplaybreaks[4]`.

Comment: "When all else fails, read the manual."